# Write a Java class to use in another Java class

Tags: java, object

I'm a Java noob.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
//File 1
public class Class1
{
   //....does some stuff
}

//File 2
public class Class2
{
   //..also does some stuff including:
   Class1 c = new Class1(); 
}
```

**File 1 and File 2 are in the same directory.**

To compile, I'm using the command:

```
javac Class2.java
```

This is giving me errors of the form:

```
Error: Cannot find symbol Class1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: are they in 2 different files ? or in a single file ?

Comment: If they're in different files, but the same directory, you don't need to import--same-package classes are magically available. If they're not in the default package (no `package` declaration) then you need to use the fully-qualified class name (including the entire package), or a wildcard import.

Comment: at first compile Class1 using javac Class1.java then compile Class2.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two files `Class1.java` and `Class2.java` are in the same directory, (and assuming you have declared the class you want to use as) you do not need to do any import at all in order to use one from the other; Java will find the other class automatically.

So in `Class2.java` you can simply do:

```
public class Class2 {
    void someMethod() {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in the same folder, you shouldn't have to import, if they aren't then you need to specify the package like `import java.util.Scanner;`. In Java you don't suffix with an extension.

What are you using to write your code in?

Comment: Actually, this isn't true. you can have more than one class in a file, it's just that only one of them can be public, and that one must match the name of the file.

Comment: @WirthLuce I thought they had to be embedded within the main class, although I've never written a secondary class in a file that wasn't embedded.

Comment: Yeah, it's honestly not very useful (and is IMO pretty ugly), but it's just a bit of trivia that I picked up the other day from one of my professors. The argument in support of it is that it will not have access to the private members of the public class in the file.

Comment: @WirthLuce Well, either way I've removed the erroneous information. Thanks! I've used Java for some time but never had a need to see if this worked or test it.

Comment: They're in the same folder, yet I'm still getting these errors.

Comment: @CaseyPatton What are you using to write your code in, just a text editor or an IDE of some kind? If you're using a Text Editor I'd suggest NetBeans which will help with a lot of problems you may run into doing things by hand.

Answer (score 0):

For using multiple classes in one file take a look into this [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/manypublicclassesinonefile.shtml)

If you are writing your classes in two different files and they are in the same package it doesn't require to import them in order to use it. But if you are compiling them manually (using command prompt) make sure you have compiled all the .java file. Otherwise you will get errors.

If you are writing them in different package make sure these classes are public in order to use them. And yes in this case you have to import the package containig the class that you want to use. Again make sure all the classes are compiled if you are using command promt.

My suggestion is to use a good IDE (there are many :)) for doing your code because they assist you much more than we do :)

Answer (score 0):

On base class,

```
package ABC;

public class PQR {

// Do stuff

}


import ABC.*;

class XYZ {
 // Use the PQR class method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand the question - are you trying to use an inner class (one class definition inside another class definition) or are these classes separate and independent? imports are required to define the packages/ classes you would have an access to, the ones in the same package are available by default. So if these are in the same package, you don't really need any imports. Also, both these classes need to be visible to each other. When you say it doesn't work, what error do you get?

one way to use inner classes is e.g. outer.new Class1() (where outer is an object of the class that encapsulates Class1). If these are not inner classes, they need to be in separate .java files.

Btw, it is always recommended to provide an access modifier (public, private, protected) explicitly.

Full code listing with error messages would help me give a better answer...